# Pivoting DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm trying to pivot my df from wide to long, and I am attempting to replicate R's `dplyr::pivot_longer()` function. I have tried `pd.wide_to_long()` and `pd.melt()` but have had no success in correctly formatting the df. I also attempted using `df.pivot()` and come to the same conclusion.

Here is what a subset of the df (called `df_wide`) looks like: Rows are Store Numbers, Columns are Dates, Values are Total Sales

[image: Subset of df_wide]

My current function looks like this:

```
df_wide.pivot(index = df_wide.index, 
              columns = ["Store", "Date", "Value"], # Output Col Names
              values = df_wide.values)
```

My desired output is a df that looks like this:

[image: Desired output]

- Note - this question is distinct from merging, as it is looking at changing the structure of a single data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack() function is useful to achieve your objective, then reformat as needed:

```
pd.DataFrame( df.stack() ).reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'level_0':'store', 'level_1':'Date', 0:'Value'})
```